# Scaling png properly to navigationbar bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have a png which is transparent and sized 500x223. I would like to make it fit my navbar.

```
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="forside.jsp"> 
            <img src="pictures/vftlogo.png">
      </a>
```

and styled the navbar-brand like so

```
.navbar-brand{      
    float: left;
    min-height: 55px;
    padding: 0 15px 5px;       
}
```

The image is way too large for the navigationbar, and I cannot seem to set the min,max height and width properties within the .navbar-brand. It seems like something is overwriting it, but I am not sure at all.
**EDIT: Changing the maximum and minimum height properties doesn't change the size nor placement of the picture**

```
<style>
    .navbar{
        margin-bottom:0;
        border-radius:0;
        padding: 1% 0;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        border: 0;
        background-color: #ffff90;
        color: #000000;
    }

    .navbar-brand{      
        float: left;
        min-height: 55px;
        padding: 0 15px 5px;       
    }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav
    .active a:focus, .navbar-inverse .active a:hover {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #ffff90;

    }

</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-headear">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavBar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="forside.jsp"> 
                <img src="pictures/vftlogo.png">
            </a>
        </div>     
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"Home</a>
                <li><a href="#">Forside</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Om os</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Find vej</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Use it as a background image and use "background-size: cover;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try .navbar-brand img { 
And set the max-height, not the min-height. Minimum height just means the image won't get smaller than that, which doesnt help to get a large image smaller. Setting the max-height means the image won't get larger than that.

```css
.navbar{
        margin-bottom:0;
        border-radius:0;
        padding: 1% 0;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        border: 0;
        background-color: #ffff90;
        color: #000000;
    }

    .navbar-brand img {      
        float: left;
        max-height: 55px;
        padding: 0 15px 5px;       
    }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav
    .active a:focus, .navbar-inverse .active a:hover {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #ffff90;

    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-headear">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavBar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="forside.jsp"> 
                <img src="https://www.konforma.nl/sites/default/files/83900a5b6d403ddbfd4e843ea70828f4.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>     
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"Home</a>
                <li><a href="#">Forside</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Om os</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Find vej</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Editing the min and maximum height properties does not affect the pictures dimensions at all

Comment: Yes it does, but you have to target the actual img tag, not the navbar/div/container or whatever, because the image will still overflow the container.